# Internet access for EC2 private instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, nat, amazon-vpc

We would like to know if its possible to make our on-premise firewall the NAT instance for the private instance in AWS VPC for outbound internet access (to get updates for example)?

We currently have AWS VPC scenario 4 implemented.

Thanks!!

Comment: Please include all necessary details in your question. What is "VPC scenario 4"?

Comment: Hello Matt! VPC Scenario 4 is the AWS VPC with private subnet only and hardware VPN access - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/VPC_Scenario4.html?tag=ad-backfill-amzn-no-or-one-good-20

Comment: Include all necessary details in your question. The AWS documentation link may change in the future (not work anymore), or "scenario 4" may become "scenario 5" due to a change in the documentation.

Answer (score 2):

For [Scenario 4: VPC with a Private Subnet Only and Hardware VPN Access](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/VPC_Scenario4.html), **all outbound (non-VPC) traffic has to go through the customer gateway** to on-prem. So if you want to access internet, the traffic goes through on-prem and then outbound from on-prem/corporate network.

In short: From AWS VPC, if you want to access any AWS endpoint, you have to go through the corporate/customer network. You have to allow outbound in your on-prem firewall. There is no other option.

If you really want to access internet through NAT, you should have created [Scenario 3: VPC with Public and Private Subnets and Hardware VPN Access](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/VPC_Scenario3.html)

[image]

Comment: Hello helloV! Currently, in my route table, i have specified all traffic (0.0.0.0/0) to go to the virtual private gateway and on my on-premise gateway (aka firewall), there is a SNAT rule defined wherein - any traffic from AWS EC2 instance - using HTTP port - going to any ipv4 - change the source to my gateway's IP address. Logically, this makes sense to me but this is not working. Don't really know what am I doing wrong here. Or is it that technically, its impossible to access the internet from a VPC Scenario 4 private subnet?

Comment: It is possible to connect to internet, as I mentioned the traffic is routed through your corporate network (even to reach AWS endpoints). We had this exact same setup. You have to work with your IT team to let the traffic from your AWS instances go to internet. Why don't you look at the NAT table if the mapping is correct or use some tool to trace the traffic and see where it is blocked.

Comment: helloV, we are a small firm and I am the one managing the IT infrastructure. Could you please enlighten us on the correct parameters for the SNAT rule? As mentioned earlier, current parameters are as follows:

Rule type: SNAT
For traffic from: AWS EC2 instance
Using Service: HTTP
Going To: Any IPv4
Change Source To: WAN (Address)

Don't really know what we are doing wrong here!